# Pass checkbox through jquery ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

**Problem solved**

I've searched several sources of info for this kinda problems. But there's no solution exactly. The problem is I cannot pass the checkboxes value to div id with ajax. It keeps openning in a parent window. Here's my codes.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#villa_submit").click(function() {   
        var action = $("#villa_choose").attr('action');
//var form_data = { 'vid[]' : []};$("input:checked").each(function() {data['vid[]'].push($(this).val());});
var form_data = $('#villa_choose').serialize();  //suggested by Kev Price 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: form_data,
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#villa_result').html('<center><img src="/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." align="absmiddle"/> loading...</center>');
              },
            success: function(data){
                  $('#test_result').html(data);
            }
        });     
        return false;
    }); 
});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="villa_choose" id="villa_choose" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="vid[]" id="vid1" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="vid[]" id="vid2" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="vid[]" id="vid3" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="vid[]" id="vid4" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="vid[]" id="vid5" value="5" />
</form>

<div id="test_result"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried sending the form data as a serialised array? i.e. var form_data = $('#villa_choose').serialize();

Comment: @KevPrice, Your suggestion is work! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear it - I probably should have added it as a solution rather than a comment. Probably worth editing your original question to show the solution so that it is obvious

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple `<input>` elements with this same `id` attribute.  This is not allowed, `id` must be unique in the document.  Fix that and try again.

Comment: Downvoter, please indicate your reason for doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Once you fix the issues Madbreaks suggested you can get the check box values into an array like this in your jquery

`var values = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
}).get();


values will be an array that you can pass with ajax like this


var data = 'checkbox="'+values+'"';
$.ajax({
    url: "process.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        ... // change html on return
    }

});`

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your attempt. I found a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

var data = $("#villa_choose").serializeArray();

$.ajax({

url: "process.php",

type: "GET",

data: data,

cache: false,

success: function (html) {

})

});